# Center image in ImageView insinde a TableView

Tags: ios, swift

How do I center the `ImageView` inside a `TableViewCell` ? Whatever I try it is aligned to the left side ...

Here my Code for the Custom Cell Class:

```
class CustomImageCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var productImage: UIImageView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    // Customize imageView like you need
    
}
```

}

And here my Code for the TableView (at least the part where the image is gonna be displayed):

```
    case 0:
           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "image", for: indexPath) as! CustomImageCell
//            cell.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            cell.imageView?.image = MachineData.shared.machineImage
            cell.imageView?.addAspectRatioConstraint()
            
            return cell
```

And here the constraints for the `imageview`:

[image: Constraints]

[image: Constraints 2]

Comment: Is this a custom cell? Can you share the code you have tried so far?

Comment: yes it is inside a custom cell.

Comment: have you add cosnstraints ? can you show that ?

Comment: sure, i updated it @FaysalAhmed

Comment: @ilija.trkulja please check my answer below.

Comment: what are bottom and top ? are they greaterThan and lessThan constraints ? because if you are giving constant height ... you should not add top and bottom ... are you facing constraint break logs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual issue is related to the reference of the image view. The `tableViewCell` has a default imageView that can be accessed by `cell.imageView`. Now you are using default imageView instead of your `productImage`.

The image view should be `productImage`, not the `imageView`.

```
 cell.productImage.image = MachineData.shared.machineImage
```

I hope this will fix.

Comment: now the image is not displayed at all. gonna play some more with it

Comment: edit: worked fine but didnt need to add the addAspectRationConstraint()

Answer (score 0):

try to add constraints programmatically like this: first set your imageView translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false

```
yourImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = false
```

after that add your imageView and set constraints with top and bottom:

```
addSubview(yourImaview)
    yourImaview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
    yourImaview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
    yourImaview.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    yourImaview.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
```

now in the table view controller set heightForRowAt with the sum of the  imageView height+bottom and top space:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 190
}
```

I suppose that you can reply it in storyboard, assign top and bottom constraints with relative space and set heightForRowAt... hope this help